# I have a single column 82,550 items and I want to know if and where they exists in a 200 x 19,000 excel table

Tags: mysql, excel, search, schema

I have a list of items (82,000) and I want to know if they exist and if so where (row and column) in an array of 200 x 19,000.  They are both currently sitting in an excel file.

The items are all strings and can range from -5, 250.0002 to Vol Price Index

I've tried outputting the excel file to a mySQL db but it has been 10 years since I've done any I'm at a loss how to query it or even if I've created the table correctly or with the right schema.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some demo code:

```
Sub WhereIsIt()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Dim BottomRow As Long, i As Long, v As Variant
    Dim Tabl As Range, r As Range

    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set Tabl = s2.Range("A1:GR19000")
    BottomRow = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To BottomRow
        v = s1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Set r = Tabl.Find(What:=v, After:=Tabl(1, 1))
        If r Is Nothing Then
            s1.Cells(i, 2).Value = "Not Found"
        Else
            s1.Cells(i, 2).Value = r.Address(0, 0)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Where `Sheet1` has the list and `Sheet2` has the table.

**EDIT#1:**

Macros are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the macro from the Excel window:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: HI, thank you for the swift response.  This is a very beginner question.  where do I put the code?  It has been a long time since I used any db stuff that I am exceptionally rusty even so far as a total noob.

Comment: @Adam  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Hi Thank you very much!  Much appreciated!

Comment: Hi,again, thank you for your response.  I'm finding using this method, as I hit searching 5600 in my list the process slows down considerably and any more and excel become unresponsive.  This happens even if I alter the count so it only runs from 5300 - 5500 rows.